# How to link table row to external URL with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I my app I have a table like this:

```
<tr data-url="/entry/57/edit">
  <td>
    Text
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="https://www.external.com">Link 1</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="https://www.external.com" target="_blank">Link 2</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
function TableRow() {

  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr[data-url]');

  rows.forEach(row => {
    row.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      handleClick(row, e);
    });
  });

  function handleClick(row, e) {
    let url = row.getAttribute('data-url');
    window.document.location = url;
  }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', TableRow);
```

How come that clicking on **Link 1** takes me to `www.external.com` (which is what I want) but clicking on **Link 2** takes me to `/entry/57/edit` (which is *not* what I want)?

I want both links to take me to `www.external.com`. How can this be done?

Comment: `stopPropagation()`?

Comment: HTML forbids nesting of “interactive” elements, such as links, for good reason. Here you are trying to implement something HTML does explicitly not all allow, “through the back door”, via JavaScript. IMHO this does not need a technical solution, but is a UI/UX fail that needs to be remedied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pavel already pointed out you need to stop event propagation. Otherwise after openening the new tab the event still propagates to the click handler of the table row.

Adding a click listener to your anchors that will stop event propagation should fix your problem

```
function TableRow() {

  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr[data-url]');

  rows.forEach(row => {
    row.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      handleClick(row, e);
    });
  });

  function handleClick(row, e) {
    let url = row.getAttribute('data-url');
    window.document.location = url;
  }

  const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('table tr[data-url] a');
  anchors.forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  });

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', TableRow);
```